# how to use certain component in directives in angularjs2

Tags: angular

I write a directive,and I want to listen a click event .When the click event trigger, I can modify the property of certain component.
But I find that i invoke the component failly..Becauseof @AfterViewInit? Can I use @HostListener in AfterViewInit?

---

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer,OnInit, ViewChild,AfterViewInit, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {TextInputComponent} from '../common/textInput/text_input.conponent';
@Directive({
selector:'[custum-input]'
})
export class MyDirectives implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{
constructor(private el:ElementRef,private renderer:Renderer){}
 @ViewChild(TextInputComponent) private textInput:TextInputComponent;
 @HostListener('click') onClick() {
   this.highlight('blue');
   this.textInput.isShow=true;
  }
private highlight(color:string){
 this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement,'backgroundColor',color);
}
```

Comment: How is `@HostListener()` related to `AfterViewInit` in your example? What doesn't work?

Comment: No idea what ` try to put @HostListener() into AfterViewInit` means. You can not `@HostListener()` into a method, only on top tof one. I don't understand what yyou try to accomplish.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer：I haven't related to AfterViewInit, I try to put @HostListener() into AfterViewInit,but this method is wrong. Do you know how to relate?

Comment: I write a 'input' component, this component will widely use in other templates. So I want to write a directive, when i click , I can set the property 'isShow' of the 'input' component to true..that means the 'input' component show on the screen.